# How To Display Tooltip When Customer On Mouse Hover Add to Cart Button

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, addtocart, additional-information

I need to display some information before going to buy products, How can i add tooltip when customer on mouse hover the add to cart button.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8044981/1409718

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your **app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml**
put below code after your **Add to Cart** `button` tag completes.

```
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
    <span class="add-to-cart-tooltip"><div class="arrow-left"></div> <span class="tooltip-text"><?php echo $this->__("YOUR TOOLTIP TEXT HERE.") ?></span>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
</div>
```

Now add below CSS in the same file.

```
<style>
.add-to-cart-buttons {
    position: relative;
}
.add-to-cart-buttons .add-to-cart-tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 5px;
}
.add-to-cart-buttons:hover .add-to-cart-tooltip, .add-to-cart-buttons:active .add-to-cart-tooltip {
    display: inline-flex;
}
.arrow-left {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-right:10px solid #8e8e8e; 
}
.tooltip-text{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 7px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Not working,, its look like,

Comment: https://snag.gy/ibZmCw.jpg

Comment: Source Code : https://snag.gy/wK03fO.jpg

Comment: I have used the code in rwd theme and it's working correctly. You may need to make changes to CSS to display it right.

Comment: @ jaimin :  Nope,    Still not working ...

Comment: Try adding a div `<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">` around your buttons and tooltip. Check updated answer for code

Comment: its working,,,,,,

Comment: Thank you Jaimin Bhai its working for me